# How to save data from query, in array of string, Firebase iOS?

Tags: ios, arrays, database, swift, firebase

I want to make a user query, removing the name of each, and go keeping the names in an array, then display them on a table. The problem is I can not keep them in the settlement, how can I fix it? Thus I make the query to extract the names of users:

```
var users = [String]()
let ref = Firebase(url:"https:mydatabase/users")
ref.queryOrderedByChild("name").observeEventType(.ChildAdded,
    withBlock: { snapshot in
        if let username = snapshot.value["name"] as! String {
            self.users.append(username)
            print("username")
        }
    })
```

So I have my users table in firebase

[image: firebase screenshot]

The username var does have the name, but when adding the content of the var the settlement, does not, at the time of execution of the application does not throw any errors.

Comment: Sorry could you please elaborate? What do you mean by settlement?

Comment: sorry, my english is very bad, i can't save the "username" var, in the "users" array

Comment: what happens when you `print(username)` (don't use quotes)?

Comment: ok, the problem is when I want to save the variable (usersname) in the array(users), it does not., help mee

Answer (score 0):

There are just a few typo's your code

Try this:

```
let usersRef = self.myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("users")
usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("name").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if let username = snapshot.value["name"] as? String {
            self.userArray.append(username)
            print("\(username)")
        }
    })
```

Be sure to define the userArray as a property of the class so it will be available to other functions.

```
class MyClass: NSObject {

    let myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://your-app.firebaseio.com")
    var userArray = [String]()
```

Comment: i'm sorry, thanks for answared, you helped me a lot of