# Swift crashes when listing to value changes on Firebase

Tags: arrays, swift

Trying to get my question answered ([Retrieve Boolean array from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058444/retrieve-boolean-array-from-firebase)) I am trying to solve the question by myself. I think I am almost done but 1 thing is bugging me. I want to retrieve a boolean array and store it in a boolean array in my app.

This is what I got:

```
if snapshot.key == "whatAchievementsunlocked"
                    {
                        whatAchievementsUnlocked.removeAll()
                        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                            for x in snapshots
                            {
                                print(x.value!) //prints 0
                                var valueForIndexX = x.value as! Int //crash
                                print(valueForIndexX)
                                if valueForIndexX == 0
                                {
                                    whatAchievementsUnlocked.append(false)
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    whatAchievementsUnlocked.append(true)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Why would it crash there? If I use as?, the output would be nil. I also tried to use var valueForIndexX = Int(x.value!) But that gives me an error: Cannot invoke initializer for type Int with an argument list of type (Any). The output of x.value! is clearly an Int, why would this result in an error? The debug just shows "(lldb)". What am I doing wrong?\

Comment: Why you need to convert it to integer since it already an integer

Comment: You say you're retrieving an array of `Bool` - do you mean that `x in snapshots` is `Bool`?  If so, why try to convert it to `Int` when it should be `Bool`?

Comment: You should never use `as!` unless you're 100% sure the value can be case as that type.  Why not try saying `if let valueForIndexX = x.value as? Bool...` and see if that solves it.

Comment: @digit its of type (Any), not integer.

Comment: @Russell, yes and no. The array is boolean in Firebase, but when retrieving it, Firebase replaces true with 1's and false with 0's.

Comment: @creeperspeak, I am 100% sure the value can be cased that way, since the prints always showing me integers. I tried your answer as well but no result, it won't execute any code.

Comment: @Petravd1994 how about putting a breakpoint at the line that crashes and try casing in the debugger.  Do you know how to do that?  Then you can try printing `x.value as? Int` and `x.value as? Bool`, etc. until you find what works.

Comment: @Petravd1994 Google's docs says `Data types returned: + NSDictionary + NSArray + NSNumber (also includes booleans) + NSString`, so it looks like you'll need to say `x.value as? NSNumber`.  Always check the docs.